# Where can I get a list of SCORM 1.2 CMI properties?

Tags: properties, scorm, scorm1.2

I am currently working on SCORM 1.2 learning content. I am quite new to SCORM and I can't seem to find all a list of "cmi." properties I can use.

I have been using the following tool: http://www.scormsoft.com/trident to give me a fair idea of the references available through its built in intellisense. Unfortunately, this product can only create SCORM 2004 packages.

Can SCORM 2004 properties be used in 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SCORM 2004 is a major overhaul of the 1.2 Runtime, they are not interchangeable, although similar in many ways. I would recommend the following process:

- There is a mostly accurate diagramm of the RTE that can be found [here](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/29166651/SCORM-12-RUN-TIME-ENVIRONMENT-DATA-TYPES), it's a really great overview.
- Set up a local [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) instance. This LMS has a really good player, and insted of using the ADL Sample RTE, this LMS actually has reporting, so you can see what a typical LMS will do with your data.
- Reverse engineer the SCORM 1.2 Conformance Test Suite if necessary
- RTFM if you need advice on the criticall propertys like *lesson_status* or *lesson_mode*

The last two Points can all be found at [ADL directly](http://legacy.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/Previous%20Versions/SCORM%201.2).

Of course there are alternative testing environments or freely available demo curses, but this should get you  pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Very useful info. Many Thanks. I managed to find another site with a list of runtime references: http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/